# How to dump postgres on google compute engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-app-engine, heroku

I'm coding on ruby on rails. I was working on Heroku, but on a new project, I pushed it on Google Cloud platform.

As it's described in the tutorial, I created a GAE rails app, deployed it with `gcloud app deploy` and I created a compute engine to host the postgres server. It's costing me 50$/month.

Everything is working fine except the response time - sometimes it takes 16 seconds to display a page.

I try to push the code on Heroku with the same database, and get an answer in 4 seconds.

My question is simple: How can I dump the postgres database from google compute engine (to restore it on Heroku)?

EDIT 1: I'm using postgres on the google compute engine as in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/deploy-postgres), not Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app engine flexible environment, you are storing your data into Cloud SQL Instance.

Thus, after you connect to your Cloud SQL instance through Cloud SQL Proxy ([described in the tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-sql)), you can dump your data normally with any Postgres client.

---

Update: OK, I misunderstood that you are using Cloud SQL.

If you created a postgres server as a Compute Engine Instance, you have to know 3 informations to dump it.

You'll see the **"Admin user"** and **"Admin password"** in "Deployment Manager" -> "library" on GCP,
and **"External IP address"** for your instance by clicking "Instance" in the same page.

Once you get these information, you can connect your postgres server as usual.

```
$ psql -h <External IP> -p 5432 -U <Admin user>
Password for user postgres: <Admin password>
```

If this command succeeded, you can also dump the content from the server by "pg_dump" command.